# Subclass generic pydantic superclass and refer to generic type later

Tags: generics, mypy, pydantic

I'm trying to build a pydantic model to parse the following two yaml situations:

```yaml
parent:
  blablabla:
    ...

# or...

parent:
  thing1:
    blablabla:
      ...
  thing2:
    blablabla:
      ...
```

In other words, `parent` may either have one of something or two of something, where the 'something' could be anything (ie generic, here denoted by 'blablabla') and I don't want to specify a useless header like 'thingX' in the first case.

In a pydantic model, I can represent this as such:

```py
X = TypeVar("X")

class Thing2(BaseModel, Generic[X]):
    thing1: X
    thing2: X

    def choose(self, first: bool) -> X:
        return self.thing1 if first else self.thing2

class Parent(BaseModel, Generic[X]):
    parent: X | Thing2[X]
```

This works fine, but say I want to add some common methods between the two cases. My naive attempt was to wrap the single case in its own type and add the method there:

```py
X = TypeVar("X")

class Thing1(Generic[X]):
    def common_method(self, ...) -> ...:
        return ...

class Thing2(BaseModel, Generic[X]):
    thing1: X
    thing2: X

    def choose(self, first: bool) -> X:
        return self.thing1 if first else self.thing2

    def common_method(self, ...) -> ...:
        return ...

class Parent(BaseModel, Generic[X]):
    parent: Thing1[X] | Thing2[X]
```

The problem with this is I now have no way (that I know of) to isolate the 'X' from the first case. Something like this doesn't typecheck:

```py
def flat(x: Thing1[X] | Thing2[X]) -> X:
    if isinstance(x, Thing1):
        return x # This is a Thing1[X] and not an X
    elif isinstance(x, Thing2):
        return x.thing1
    else:
        assert_never(x)
```

Since `Thing2` has a method for isolating `X` (due to the fact that it stored each instance of `X` in its attributes) it is trivial to isolate it later. My naive sense is there should be a way to do this with `Thing1`; something like this but I have no idea how to create the `__init__` method:

```py
class Thing1(Generic[X]):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        # somehow make a new 'X' here using whatever args we were given
        self.x: X = ??? # and store the value here

    @property
    def unwrap(self) -> X:
        return self.x

    def common_method(self, ...) -> ...:
        return ...
```

Is something like this possible to achieve?

versions

- python 3.11
- mypy 1.7.1
- pydantic 1.10